# PHP code to download file separately when clicked on button?

Tags: php

I had done uploading code and stored all my file in C:\wamp\www\Etutor\Uploaded_files.

db-etutor
table-fileuploads

Now i want to download these file when i click on download button seperately for each file.

Using PHP code

Comment: You want the client to be able to download a file? You'll do that with Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: ya after logging user will be downloding a file

Comment: You can't use PHP in the client. Browsers only understand Javascript.

Comment: okk thank u ...but can u help how??

Comment: Do you know Javascript?

Comment: It's not clear enough what you're asking. How and where did you upload, how are you trying to download, and why do you need to download something you've uploaded? Can't you use your original files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you stored your file info/name to database? If yes, then follow thes steps -

1) retrieve these data from database

2) create multiple links for these files using **for** loop. Then add html code like this `<a href="your file path info">file name</a>`.

Hope now you can do it quite easily.

If you have not stored it in database, then you need to do it using javascript.

Write code like this -

```
 <script>

 var a = document.createElement('a');
 var linkText = document.createTextNode("my file name");
 a.appendChild(linkText);
 a.title = "my file name";
 a.href = "http://example.com";
 document.body.appendChild(a);
 </script>
```

Comment: ya i ve stored in database as the file was upload it will be stored in database and will be showing list with download button in a php file

Comment: Then use first portion & you will find your desired output. Let me know if you still face any more problem.